# Remove conditions in a C program for speedup

Tags: c, optimization, cell, conditional-statements

I have a number crunching C program which involves a main loop with two conditionals:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    if (k == i || k == j) continue;
    ...(calculate a, b, c, d (depending on k)  
    if (a*a + b*b + c*c < d*d) {break;}
  } //k
 } //j
} //i
```

The hardware here is the SPE of the Cell processor, where there is a big penalty when using branching. So in order to optimize my program for speedup I need to remove these 2 conditionals, do you know about good strategies for this?

Comment: What happens in the  .... break;

Comment: just only the break, so:   {break;}

Comment: Isn't there penalty only for incorrectly predicted branches? May be a hint to compiler about expected results would help?

Comment: @blaze, how could I tell that to te compiler?

Comment: @Werner, you'd have to check the optimization guide for your processor. It may tell you something about the way the processor predicts branches. E.g. modern Intels predict conditional branches to be not taken. Then you reformulate the branching condition to match expectations of the processor.

Comment: @Werner depends on your compiler. I'm only familiar with gcc and it has __builtin_expect: if (__builtin_expect (ptr != NULL, 1)) blah();

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, you could break it into multiple loops, eg change:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
      if(k==i || k == j) continue;
      // other code
    }
  }
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < min(i, j); k++) {
      // other code
    }
    for(int k = min(i, j) + 1; k < max(i, j); k++) {
      // other code
    }
    for(int k = max(i, j) + 1; k < 1000; k++) {
      // other code
    }
  }
```

To remove the second, you could store the previous total and use it in the for loop conditions, i.e.:

```
int left_side = 1, right_side = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < min(i, j) && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // other code (calculate a, b, c, d)
      left_side = a * a + b * b + c * c;
      right_side = d * d;
    }
    for(int k = min(i, j) + 1; k < max(i, j) && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
    for(int k = max(i, j) + 1; k < N && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
  }
```

Implementing `min` and `max` without branching could also be tricky. Maybe this version is better:

```
int i, j, k, 
  left_side = 1, right_side = 0;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  // this loop covers the case where j < i
  for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    k = 0;
    for(; k < j && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // other code (calculate a, b, c, d)
      left_side = a * a + b * b + c * c;
      right_side = d * d;
    }
    k++; // skip k == j
    for(; k < i && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
    k++; // skip k == i
    for(; k < N && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
  }
  j++; // skip j == i
  // and now, j > i
  for(; j < N; j++) {
    k = 0;
    for(; k < i && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // other code (calculate a, b, c, d)
      left_side = a * a + b * b + c * c;
      right_side = d * d;
    }
    k++; // skip k == i
    for(; k < j && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
    k++; // skip k == j
    for(; k < N && left_side >= right_side; k++) {
      // same as in previous loop
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a very good idea! but just in the case I had not the other "if" inside. now the program has to evaluat the second "if" three times, so performance degrades

Comment: Don't the conditions in the `for` statements induce extra branching ?

Comment: @Alexandre - No more than you'd have anyway. You'll need to run the loop that many times, checking for loop termination each time. All this code just reduces (possibly) redundant loop checking.

Comment: @Alexander C.: I was assuming 'or' constructions (where multiple code paths could occur - so, including 'if' statements) that were branches. This way, it's do the thing or do nothing (not even break). But you could well be right - I just assumed the for conditions were ok because they appeared in the question.

Comment: this is indeed interesting. will check it out and tell you, thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to precompute min(i,j) and max(i,j) and to save their values in a variable. You don't want to risk having the compiler recalculate min & max every iteration of k.

Comment: here you can get min and max for integers without branching: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Comment: thanks, the idea is very good, but I forgot to say that //calculate a,b,c,d depends on k, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 'sje397'.

Besides this, you provide too little information about your problem. You say branching is pricey. But how often does it actually happen? Maybe your problem is that compiler-generated code does branching in the common scenario?

Perhaps you could re-arrange your `if`-s. The implementation of the `if` is actually compiler-dependent, bust many compilers treat it in a straight-forward way. That is: `if` - common - `else` - rare (jump).

Then try the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    if (k != i && k != j)
    {
      ...(calculate a, b, c, d)  
      if (a*a + b*b + c*c >= d*d)
      {
        ...
      } else
        break;
    }
  } //k
 } //j
} //i
```

**EDIT:**

Of course you may go into assembler level to ensure correct code generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would look first at your `calculate` code, because that could swamp all these branching issues. Some sampling would find out for sure.

However, it looks like you're doing, for each `i,j`,  a linear search for the first point inside a sphere. Could you have 3 arrays, one for each of the X, Y, and Z axes, and in each array store indexes of all the original points in ascending order by that axis? That could facilitate a nearest-neighbor search. Also, you might be able to use an in-cube test, rather than an in-sphere test, since you're not hunting for the closest point, but only a nearby point.

Comment: the idea of the calculation is rather close to your guess, but implemented in a different way, you are very smart :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you actually need the first if-statement? Even if it jumps one calculation when k equals i or j, the penalty for checking it every iteration is very costly. Also, keep in mind that if N is not a constant, the compiler probably wont be able to unroll the for loops.

Although, if it's a cell processor, the compiler might even try to vectorize the loops.

If the for loops compiles to normal iterative loops it could be an idea to make them compare with zero instead, as the decrement operation will often do the comparison for you when it hits zero.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```

...can become...

```
for (i = N; i != 0; i--) {
```

Although, if "i" is used as an index or a variable in a calculation, you might get performance degradation as you will get cache misses.